# How to extract a particular word from a sentence in SQL database?

Tags: java

I doing a java project. In this, I have a database table named **posts**. In this post table there are two fields, they are *user* and *msg*.

if *msg* column contains **It is a earthquake** data. I need a `sql` query to extract only the word *earthquake* from the column. Can I do this ? Help me with Your codes friends......

Comment: Have you tried using `like '%word%'`?

Comment: I tried but not get the answer

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to work with databases if you have no idea how to use SQL?

Comment: if you know the word you are extracting, why do you need to extract it?  Wouldn't you just need to know which users or how many posts contain this occurrence?

Comment: Why did you tag JAVA ? its related to SQL

Comment: It is a concept in my Java project. I have to extract only  a particular work from the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select * from posts where msg like '%earthquake%'`.  Note that this query is case sensitive, and hella inefficient.  (And also won't play nice with indexes).

Oracle DB has a handy text indexing feature for exactly this kind of problem: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm

It's surprisingly tricky because as soon as you want to look at "words", you're into the realm of language processing rather than simple regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from posts where lower(msg) like '%earthquake%'.
```

This query is not case sensitive. This is more efficient.

Comment: More efficient than what?